# Enumerate terminals in extensions API

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions, vscode-tasks

I know how to create a new terminal from a VSCode extension using the `vscode.window.createTerminal` method. This method returns a reference to the terminal so that I can subsequently interact with it, for example, by sending strings to it etc.

I would really like to be able to interact with *existing* terminals in VSCode but cannot find any APIs to do this. Is it possible to enumerate all open integrated terminals in VSCode?

Answer (score 2):

VS Code 1.26 added [`window.terminals`](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_26#_terminal-access-api). This readonly array allows you to access all terminals

There is also:

- `window.activeTerminal`- Currently active terminal or undefined if none.
- `window.onDidChangeActiveTerminal` - Event fired when the active terminal changes
- `window.onDidOpenTerminal` - Event fired when a new terminal is created (either by an extension or by the user)